# How do I use a date (selected from a date picker) to allow me to segue to a specific View Controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, datepicker, segue, viewcontroller

In my app the different View Controllers represent each month.

I want the date to lead me to the corresponding controller.

My goal is to create an app that presents the user their Zodiac when chosen their birthday from a date picker and clicked continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get month number and after that select the controller with switch help:

```
let monthNumber = 10

switch monthNumber {
case 1:
    *show some controller*
case 2:
    *show some controller*
case 3:
    *show some controller*
case 4:
    *show some controller*
case 5:
    *show some controller*
case 6:
    *show some controller*
case 7:
    *show some controller*
case 8:
    *show some controller*
case 9:
    *show some controller*
case 10:
    *show some controller*
case 11:
    *show some controller*
case 12:
    *show some controller*
default:
    break
}
```

But this is not good solution. Good is send date parameter to your Zodiac controller and configure it with this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly select the Date From Date Picker:

**Step 1:- Extract Month component from it:**

```
let dateComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: selectedDateFromDatePicker)
print(dateComponent.month!)
```

**Step:-2 Push to specific View Controller According to Month:**

```
    if dateComponent.month! == 1{
        //January
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 2{
        //Feb
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 3{
        //Mar
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 4{
        //Apr
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 5{
        //May
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 6{
        //June
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 7{
        //July
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 8{
        //Aug
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 9{
        //Sep
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 10{
        //Oct
    }else if dateComponent.month! == 11{
        //Nov
    }else{
        //Dec
    }
```